# click is not triggering the jquery function

Tags: jquery

The first function places a particular list from a hidden div depending on which item is clicked.  This function works correctly when clicking the 'a' link.  After clicking a link, it will remove the class from all the list and add the new class to the correct list item.  It then loads the hidden list into the orange_box div.

The second function is supposed to do something similar, but it is not triggering on click of the secondlist class.  When I remove 'a', which I thought was the culprit, nothing happens as either. Is this an issue with the HTML content being placed in another div and therefore can't be targeted?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<ul id="firstlist" class="no-list-styles inline">
    <li class="select1"><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li> | 
    <li><a href="#1_list">Access to Mental Health</a></li> | 
    <li><a href="#2_list">Diet & Exercise</a> | 
    </li><li><a href="#3_list">Tobacco Use</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="hide" id="firstlistmenu">
    <div id="1_list">
        <ul class="no-list-styles inline secondlist">
            <li class="select2"><a href="#1_programs">Programs</a></li> | 
            <li><a href="#1_policies">Policies</a></li> | 
            <li><a href="#1_success">Success Stores</a></li> | 
            <li><a href="#1_tools">Tools</a></li> | 
            <li><a href="#1_funding">Funding</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="orange_box">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firstlist a').click(function(){
        $('#firstlist li').removeClass('select1');
        $(this).parent().addClass('select1');
        href=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#orange_box').html($('#firstlistmenu '+href).html());
        $('#orange_box li:first').addClass('select2');
    });

    $('#orange_box .secondlist a').click(function(){
        alert('hello');
        $('.secondlist li').removeClass('select2');
        $(this).parent().addClass('select2');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot direclty attach an event handler to elements that don't exist yet. Try with delegated events.

```
$('#orange_box').on('click', '.secondlist a', function() {...});
```

You can find more information about direct and delegated events on jquery [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Take a look to **Direct and delegated events** section.

Comment: @alrightgame: `orange_box` is empty when DOM loads, there is no element inside according html you provided.

Answer (score 3):

Use on instead of binding with click, so that when you change the class of element the event is binded with new class.

```
$('#orange_box').on('click', '.classThatChanged', function(){
    alert('hello');
    $('.secondlist li').removeClass('select2');
    $(this).parent().addClass('select2');
});
```

#### delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers,
>   [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `on`, instead of the `click` shortcut. The `on` method works for current and **future** elements.

> $('#orange_box .secondlist a').on( 'click', function(){
>           alert('hello');
>           $('.secondlist li').removeClass('select2');
>           $(this).parent().addClass('select2');
>       });

Answer (score 1):

`#orange_box` is empty when you register the click - so it registers on an empty list - so it does nothing.

You want to use jquery `on` ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ ) to bind the click like so

```
$('#orange_box').on('click', '.secondlist a', function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're copying the HTML for .secondlist into #orange_box, the events are not taken with it. You need to bind the events after copying it to #orange_box, or just move the dom node itself.